# Model not completely binding in POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, model

Not understanding what I am overseeing here ...
I have a Model which I render in a View.

**This is the SubscriptionViewModel:**

```
public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }

public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }

public List<DateTime> SomeDates { get; set; }
```

In the View I have populated a table with data from the SubscriptionViewModel.
In each table row there is an If/else statement, where in each part I placed a Form so that the data can be posted back to the SubscriptionController, this is a pseudo example:

```
if (condition)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Subscription", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("text", "Subscribe", new { @date = item }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-radius" })
    }
}
else
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("UnSubscribe", "Subscription", FormMethod.Post))
    {                                                                   
        @Html.ActionLink("text", "UnSubscribe", new { @date = item }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-radius" })
    }
}
```

This is the SubscriptionContoller method being triggered:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscriptionViewModel model, string date)
{
    return View();
}
```

The POST is triggered and my Model is not NULL, the **date** parameter also has the correct value, the only thing which is lost is the parameters from **Subscription** Entity from my SubscriptionViewModel. They are not NULL but they just don't have their initial values when coming to the View initially...

No clue what I am overseeing, I tried using `TempData.Keep()` into the View (which I never needed to do before) but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestion is welcome!
Thank you!

Comment: What does your data retrieval look like?

Comment: How is the post triggered when there are only hyperlinks in your form?

Comment: @JasonRoner, Do you mean how I populate my Model before rendering it?

Comment: @DaveBarnett, the @Html.ActionLink("text", "Unsubscribe", ...) points to the Action where it is supposed to be posted. I saw this in an example online.

Comment: That will give you a hyperlink which means the form won't be posting.  You will be going to the subscribe method via a get request which can work but is not right way to be doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you don't want the values for the Subscription to come from the form but rather stay as they were when the values are originally sent to the view which sounds like what you are after.

You need to include the values for the subscription in the form using hidden fields (see example 1).  Alternatively you will need to populate the subscription in your post method in the same way that it is in your get method (see example 2).

Here are 2 simple examples demonstrating what I mean

Suppose this is your subscription class

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Example 1**

***The HiddenField way***

The controller

```
public class SubscriptionController : Controller
{       
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Subscribe()
    {
        var viewModel = new SubscriptionViewModel
        {
            Subscription = GetSubscription()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscriptionViewModel model, string date)
    {
        return View();
    }

    private Subscription GetSubscription()
    {
        return new Subscription
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "My Subscription"
        };
    }
}
```

The view

```
@model {The namespace}.SubscriptionViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Subscription", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //Other fields 
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Subscription.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Subscription.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

**Example 2**

***The get back in the controller way***

The controller

```
public class SubscriptionController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Subscribe()
    {
        var viewModel = new SubscriptionViewModel
        {
            Subscription = GetSubscription()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscriptionViewModel model, string date)
    {
        model.Subscription = GetSubscription();

        return View();
    }

    private Subscription GetSubscription()
    {
        return new Subscription
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "My Subscription"
        };
    }
}
```

The view

```
@model {The namespace}.SubscriptionViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Subscription", FormMethod.Post))
{     
    //Other fields 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Comment: I want to initially load the View with data from the Model I populated, the purpose of the View is for the user to select a Date which the Post should add to the Initial data from the model, so I guess I shouldn't use a @Html.ActionLink(...) but a input field? Will try this and post back, thank you for the suggestions and information!

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  Add the date information as a hidden field.  You're welcome!

Comment: I did that but I still have empty values for my controller parameter (Model). I don't get that the Model itself is not NULL, just the properties of the model are unassigned ... It seems to loose the values but still keeping it's instance (not being NULL). Any suggestions?

Comment: OK I got certain things mixed up and will need to rethink if what I am doing is good or not. Right now I have all values I need in my model when I load & show he View, except the Date which I want the user to select. So I only have 1 razor helper, HiddenFor which allows me to retrieve the selected date (thanks to you @Dave Barnett) but I don't get why my model doesn't have it's values when arriving in the Controller, is it because I need to have all model's properties defined within the Html.BeginForm(...) scope?

Comment: Yes it will need to have them in each Html.BeginForm().

Comment: OK thank you for confirming this! Will rethink my approach! Good day/night! Thanks again!